# how to configure Ant Design with Webpack 3

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

**Fix and solution:**

Thanks to @BoyWithSilver, long story short, here are what I did to fix my problems:

1. added .less into extensions section
2. removed unnecessary codes in webpack.config.json e.g. removed the extract-text-webpack-plugin
3. downgrade less from 3.0.1 to 2.7.0 fixed heaps of errors: length of undefined in index.less file in antd.

---

**Update 3**

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mobx-reactjsx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": dfsdfsdfsd",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --progress --inline",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "reactjs",
    "boilerplate",
    "mobx",
    "starter-kit",
    "firebase",
    "re-base"
  ],
  "author": "Winston Fan",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://horizontalvision.azurewebsites.net/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.6.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "less": "^3.0.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "less-vars-to-js": "^1.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.2.1",
    "firebase": "^4.9.1",
    "mobx": "^3.5.1",
    "mobx-react": "^4.4.1",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^4.2.15",
    "re-base": "^3.2.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  }
}
```

---

Update 2:

1. After removed the context option :
   // context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   in webpage.config.js
2. added

   javascriptEnabled: true
   under less-loader in webpack.config.json

I received these errors.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less Module build
>   failed:
>
> /* stylelint-disable
>   declaration-bang-space-before,no-duplicate-selectors */ ^ Cannot read
>   property 'length' of undefined
>         in F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\antd\lib\style\color\bezierEasing.less
>   (line 1, column -1)  @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.js
>   5:0-23  @ ./src/index.js  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.less Module build failed:
>
> /* stylelint-disable
>   declaration-bang-space-before,no-duplicate-selectors */ ^ Cannot read
>   property 'length' of undefined
>         in F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\antd\lib\style\color\bezierEasing.less
>   (line 1, column -1)  @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.js
>   3:0-33  @ ./src/index.js  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.less Module build failed:
>   ModuleBuildError: Module build failed:
>
> /* stylelint-disable
>   declaration-bang-space-before,no-duplicate-selectors */ ^ Cannot read
>   property 'length' of undefined
>         in F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\antd\lib\style\color\bezierEasing.less
>   (line 1, column -1)
>       at runLoaders (F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:195:19)
>       at F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:364:11
>       at F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:230:18
>       at context.callback (F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)  @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.less  @
>   ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less Module build
>   failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed:
>
> /* stylelint-disable
>   declaration-bang-space-before,no-duplicate-selectors */ ^ Cannot read
>   property 'length' of undefined
>         in F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\antd\lib\style\color\bezierEasing.less
>   (line 1, column -1)
>       at runLoaders (F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:195:19)
>       at F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:364:11
>       at F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:230:18
>       at context.callback (F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)  @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less  @
>   ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js
>   Child extract-text-webpack-plugin
>   node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist
>   node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-2!node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.less:
>          [0] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"modifyVars":{"@primary-color":"#193D71"},"root":"F://temp//Playground//mobx-reactjsx","javascriptEnabled":true}!./node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.less
>   302 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
>
> ```
> ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"modifyVars":{"@primary-color":"#193D71"},"root":"F://temp//Playground//mobx-reactjsx","javascriptEnabled":true}!./node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.less
> Module build failed:
>
> /* stylelint-disable declaration-bang-space-before,no-duplicate-selectors */
> ^
> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       in F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\antd\lib\style\color\bezierEasing.less
> ```
>
> (line 1, column -1) Child extract-text-webpack-plugin
>   node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist
>   node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-2!node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less:
>          [0] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"modifyVars":{"@primary-color":"#193D71"},"root":"F://temp//Playground//mobx-reactjsx","javascriptEnabled":true}!./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less
>   302 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
>
> ```
> ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"modifyVars":{"@primary-color":"#193D71"},"root":"F://temp//Playground//mobx-reactjsx","javascriptEnabled":true}!./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less
> Module build failed:
>
> /* stylelint-disable declaration-bang-space-before,no-duplicate-selectors */
> ^
> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       in F:\temp\Playground\mobx-reactjsx\node_modules\antd\lib\style\color\bezierEasing.less
> ```
>
> (line 1, column -1) webpack: Failed to compile.

---

Update 1:

Here is my webpack.config.json

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const fs  = require('fs');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const lessToJs = require('less-vars-to-js');
const themeVariables = lessToJs(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './scripts/ant-theme-vars.less'), 'utf8'));

module.exports = {
  watch: true,
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      use: ['babel-loader'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([
          {loader: "css-loader"},
          {loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              modifyVars: themeVariables,
              root: path.resolve(__dirname, './')
            }
          }
        ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      },]
  }
};
```

now error message becomes:

> ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   ./src/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/index.js'
>   in '/Users/Winston/tmp/Playground/mobx-reactjsx/src'  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js

(project structure)
[image: project structure]

I do have index.js under projectfolder/src

---

I'm trying to integrate Ant Design with Less support and the Import on Demand feature which is here:
https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app
in Advanced Guide section.

In this section, it uses react-app-rewired but my project uses webpack 3(my project is based on this https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-boilerplate), so cannot use the rewired command in my case.

So I found another article:
https://medium.com/@GeoffMiller/how-to-customize-ant-design-with-react-webpack-the-missing-guide-c6430f2db10f

Here is my code:

package.json

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --open",
```

webpack.config.json

```
const fs  = require('fs');

const lessToJs = require('less-vars-to-js');
const themeVariables = lessToJs(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './scripts/ant-theme-vars.less'), 'utf8'));
....
module:{
.....
rules:[
.....
test: /\.less$/,

use: [

       {loader: "style-loader"},

       {loader: "css-loader"},

       {loader: "less-loader",

options: {

modifyVars: themeVariables

         }

       }

     ]
]
}
```

index.js

```
import {Button} from 'antd';

<Button type="primary">Hi!</Button>
```

.babelrc

```
{

"presets": [

"react",

"es2015",

"stage-1"

 ],

"plugins": [

   ["import", {"libraryName": "antd", "style": true} ],

"transform-decorators-legacy"

 ]

}
```

Here is the error messages from console:
[image]

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings forgot to upload the error messages >_<; after 5 hours debugging, my brain stopped working O_O.  Updated, please see the error messages

Comment: It seems that the loader is not resolving `.less` files. Try adding `resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.less']},` to the webpack.config.js file

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings thanks man, it solves one, another appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be coming from the inability to resolve `.less` files. Adding this to `webpack.config.js` should help resolve them:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.less']
},
```

You have specified context as `src` folder in the structure. This means the entry has to be changed to `./index.js` or just `./index`
If you did not mean to have `context` key, removing it will also do the work.

Comment: thanks man, it solves one, another appears. Please see my update 1 picture for my project structure.

Comment: @Franva What is the version of `less` you are using?

Comment: hi it's ^3.0.1. I added my package.json in update 3 section

Comment: @Franva Drop it down to 2.7.0 and check again

Comment: will do it now. do I need to downgrade my less-loader as well? If yes, what version?

Comment: gosh~! it solves that problem~! thanks!!!! The last one thing is, the antd style for Button(I use Button in my project) doesn't come through

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165334/discussion-between-boy-with-silver-wings-and-franva).

Answer (score 16):

For me i just had to use `import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css`
instead of `import 'antd/dist/antd.css`

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/33327#issuecomment-997355323

Answer (score 2):

Webpack configuration (webpack.config.js):

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const fs  = require('fs');
const lessToJs = require('less-vars-to-js');
const themeVariables = lessToJs(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ant-theme-vars.less'), 'utf8'));
module.exports = {
  watch: true,
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: {
    app: './index.js',
  },  
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      moment: 'moment/src/moment'
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['env','react','stage-2']
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.js$/,
        options: {
          presets: ['env','react','stage-2'],
          plugins: [
            ['import', { libraryName: "antd", style: true }]
          ]
        },
      },
      {
      test: /\.scss?$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          loader: 'css-loader!sass-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([
          {loader: "css-loader"},
          {loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              modifyVars: themeVariables,
              root: path.resolve(__dirname, './')
            }
          }
        ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg|png|jpg,pdf)$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    contentBase: 'dist'
  }
};
```

And package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ant-design-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Ant design",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --progress --inline",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js"
   },
   "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": ""
   },
   "author": "Sivadass",
   "license": "MIT",
   "dependencies": {
      "antd": "^3.1.4",
      "moment": "^2.20.1",
      "react": "^16.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
      "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
      "babel-plugin-import": "^1.6.3",
      "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
      "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
      "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
      "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
      "less": "^2.7.3",
      "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
      "less-vars-to-js": "^1.2.1",
      "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
      "postcss-loader": "^2.0.10",
      "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
      "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
      "sugarss": "^1.0.1",
      "webpack": "^3.10.0",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
    }
 }
```

Ant theme variables configuration (ant-theme-vars.less):

```
  @primary-color: #4099ff;
  @font-size-base: 16px;
  @font-family : "Proxima Nova", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  @btn-font-size-lg: 15px;
  @btn-padding-lg : 8px 32px;
  @btn-padding-sm : 4px 16px;
```

Comment: thanks Sivadass, I have updated my webpack.config.json and new error message comes. Please see my update 1.

Comment: @Sivadass N, could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453633/change-ant-design-variables-using-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

Solution for React :

in index.js folder

- import 'antd/dist/antd.css

replace with

- import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css

Answer (score 0):

I just added that import statement into my index.scss file, then the warnings were disappeared

`@import "antd/dist/antd.css";`