# Change Ant Design variables using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using `antd` library in my application. According to the [documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme), I can customize the theme by changing the variables like:

```css
modifyVars: {
  "primary-color": "#EB564F",
   "link-color": "#0DD078",
   "success-color": "#0DD078",
   "border-radius-base": "40px",
}
```

I did something like this in my  react application adding the file `webpack.config.js` and the next code inside:

```js
// webpack.config.js
const antdRegex = /antd.+\.less$/;

module.exports = {
rules: [
    {
        test: antdRegex,
        loader: [
            "style-loader",
            "css-loader",
            {
                loader: "less-loader",
                options: {
                    lessOptions: {
                        modifyVars: {
                            "primary-color": "#EB564F",
                            "link-color": "#0DD078",
                            "success-color": "#0DD078",
                            "border-radius-base": "40px",
                        },
                        javascriptEnabled: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    }]
}
```

But the colors don't change. Why and how to solve it?

Comment: which version of less loader are you using?

Comment: @Hemanthvrm, `"less": "^4.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^7.3.0",`  is there a problem with  the version?

Comment: @Hemanthvrm, i just set `webpack.config.js`, should i set something additional to make it workable?

Comment: @Hemanthvrm, could you show the snippet of code how to change the variables?

Comment: i asked version since older version doesn't have lessOptions key... modifyVars is direct key to options..i think javascriptEnabled key should be for lessOptions instead options...
I am not sure if that going to fix it...

Comment: i use my variables in different less file and import them using lessToJs library to assign to that key...so that i don't have to make changes to my webpack config file in furure

Comment: by the way how are you importing antd ? using babel plugin or importing from less file directly?

Comment: @Hemanthvrm, `by the way how are you importing antd ? using babel plugin or importing from less file directly?`, what do you mean?

Comment: @Hemanthvrm, also i changed the code from the question. Please take a look. Basically all what i do to change the default variables is in the code that i added to my question. Should i do something else to make the code to be valid?

Comment: i am doing fresh code install..will post detailed answer.

Comment: @Hemanthvrm , Thanks, waiting for your answer

Comment: updated my answer for  CRA  webpack changes..Hope you do a fresh install and test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using `craco` in `create-react-app`

For `webpack.config.js` to take effect, you would have to eject from `create-react-app`. The `craco` package solves this problem as described in the [official guide](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Advanced-Guides).

### 1. Install the relevant `craco` packges using npm

`npm install --save-dev @craco/craco craco-less`

### 2. Change `.css` imports to `.less`

```
/* src/App.js */
import './App.css' -> './App.less';

/* src/App.less */
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css' -> '~antd/dist/antd.less';
```

### 3. Create `craco.config.js` in project root

```
const CracoLessPlugin = require("craco-less");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
      options: {
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          lessOptions: {
            modifyVars: {
              "primary-color": "#EB564F",
              "link-color": "#0DD078",
              "success-color": "#0DD078",
              "border-radius-base": "40px",
            },
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

### 4. Update scripts in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "craco start",
  "build": "craco build"
  "test": "craco test"
}
```

### 5. Done

Comment: i added the above changes and all works, but for example, if i import in `App.js` a file with `scss` extension i get an error: `Cannot find module 'sass'`, but if i i change the extension of the imported file into `less` all works again. Why the CRACO config does not allow the scss extension and how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

## Without ejecting create-react-app

For `webpack.config.js` to take effect, you would have to eject from `create-react-app`. There is a workaround which does not require ejecting your project.

### Steps

1. Install `less` globally
2. Create a `main.less` file and include `antd.less` in it
3. Redeclare the default variables you want to override
4. Compile `main.less` to `.css` and include THAT file in your app

### 1. Install `less` globally

`npm install -g less`

### 2-3. Create a `main.less` file and include `antd.less` in it then redeclare the default variables you want to override

```
@import 'node_modules/antd/dist/antd.less';
@primary-color: #EB564F;
@link-color: #0DD078;
@success-color: #0DD078;
@border-radius-base: 40px;
```

### 4. Compile `main.less` to `.css` and include THAT file in your app

Run `lessc "./src/styles/main.less" "./src/styles/css/antd.css" --js` from the root of your project then import this css file in your project.

---

Source: [Customising Ant Design (antd) theme without using react eject or any unreliable packages](https://medium.com/@aksteps/customising-ant-design-antd-theme-without-using-react-eject-or-any-unreliable-libraries-782c53cbc03b)

Comment: @re, if i run `lessc "./src/styles/main.less ./src/styles/css/antd.css" --js`, i get `lessc: ENOENT: no such file or directory`

Comment: might just be a typo because of the quotes in the command try: `lessc "./src/styles/main.less" "./src/styles/css/antd.css" --js`. if it doesnt work please provide a more detailed error message

Comment: your answer helped, but  in this way i have to increase the project with over 500kb, because that file weight almost this. Is there a solution where to change some  web-pack changes but without eject?

Comment: Have you tried the [advanced official CRA guide](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Advanced-Guides)? You have to install and understand `craco` to configure without ejecting but it should work.

Comment: See my other answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

**Please check antd documentation for installation if you doesn't want to eject your react application(created using CRA)..**

https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app
[image]

**This answer is for those who wants to install ANTD manually after ejecting create react app.**

*versions used:*

- CRA 4.0.3

React Installation Steps:

- Create react app using yarn CRA command (*yarn create react-app
  my-app*)
- Eject react app (*yarn eject*)

**CRA doesn't have less in boilerplate code(At least until 4.0.3)..
Since ANTD is in less, we do install it manually.(You can import antd css directly to skip this entire process...But antd css is not on demand, which will download styles for all components even though we don't use them)**

*versions used:*

- antd - 4.13.1
- babel-plugin-import - 1.13.3      (For importing components on
  demand)
- less- 4.0.0
- less-loader - 7.3.0
- less-vars-to-js - 1.3.0

***Steps:***

- Install all packages using this command

  yarn add antd@4.13.1 && yarn
  add babel-plugin-import@1.13.3 less@4.0.0 less-loader@7.3.0
  less-vars-to-js@1.3.0 -D

**Webpack config and setting theme**

1. In package.json install antd plugin for babel

   "plugins": [
   [
   "import",
   {
   "libraryName": "antd",
   "style": true
   }
   ]
   ]

[image]

2. Create antdTheme.less file in src folder...(we provide our theme
   settings here)

[image]

3. Modify webpack.config.js  (Modified in three places in this file)

   // Ant Design Webpack Config

   const lessToJs = require("less-vars-to-js");

   const themeVariables = lessToJs(
   fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./../src/antdTheme.less"), "utf8")
   );

   const lessRegex = /.less$/;

   const lessModuleRegex = /.module.less$/;

[image]

Add if else condition and add this code..check picture on how condition is written

```
loaders.push(
          {
            loader: require.resolve("resolve-url-loader"),
            options: {
              sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                ? shouldUseSourceMap
                : isEnvDevelopment,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                modifyVars: themeVariables,
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
          }
        );
```

[image]

Add this code for supporting less and less modules

```
// Ant Design config
            {
              test: lessRegex,
              exclude: lessModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                },
                "less-loader"
              ),
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using LESS
            // using the extension .module.less
            {
              test: lessModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: true,
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
                "less-loader"
              ),
            },
```

[image]

**After changing these files**

- Start your application using yarn start..
- You should see green as
  primary colour hence we used the same in our theme less file..
  Change them as per your requirement (Remember you have to restart
  when you make changes to theme level less file)...

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please attach all `webpack-config.js` file that will change antd variables please(all that is related to my question)? Because now i can't succeed  to get you result, because there in the file you have others settings. It will help me a lot.

Comment: give me some time, i can upload complete project to my github..
you can refer to it..

Comment: Make sure you use CRA 4.0.3 to generate project to match webpack code or use my repo directly...
https://github.com/hemanthvrm/CRA4-ANTD4

Comment: thanks for the repo. It helped, but in this way i have to `eject` my app. Is there a solution how to change the variables also using this principle, but configuring the simple react app without ejecting it?

Comment: Open antd link in my answer and refer to craco library solution..

Answer (score 0):

Works really well what @rezso.dev has said above - Without ejecting create-react-app.

Other variables that can be edited:

```
@primary-color: #1890ff; // primary color for all components
@link-color: #1890ff; // link color
@success-color: #52c41a; // success state color
@warning-color: #faad14; // warning state color
@error-color: #f5222d; // error state color
@font-size-base: 14px; // major text font size
@heading-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85); // heading text color
@text-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65); // major text color
@text-color-secondary: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45); // secondary text color
@disabled-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); // disable state color
@border-radius-base: 2px; // major border radius
@border-color-base: #d9d9d9; // major border color
@box-shadow-base: 0 3px 6px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 6px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 9px 28px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); // major shadow for layers
```

https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme